Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemoCache')
After adding React Compiler, I am seeing quite a few errors in Sentry that say:

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemoCache')

There is really not much to include as this is the only information logged in Sentry.

The stack traces show something that is completely unrelated.
The error appears to be only logged when rendering React server-side.
It is not clear whether user experience is impacted by this error.

Sharing here hoping that other people with more reactjs experience can comment.
I was not able to consistently/locally replicate the issue despite many logs in Sentry.

In specific cases where stack trace identified a file where the error originates, I was able to avoid avoid the error by excluding the file using sources rule in babel-plugin-react-compiler. However, most errors do not have obvious origin information.

Turns out it does affect end users. Just ran into this myself.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemoCache')
    at d.c (https://pillser.com/assets/compiler-runtime-CMQmO_Xw.js:9:103)
    at Bt (https://pillser.com/assets/_route-DfOihCf1.js:9:8097)
    at vi (https://pillser.com/assets/entry.client-tQKe0HOj.js:42:41982)
    at Ec (https://pillser.com/assets/entry.client-tQKe0HOj.js:42:61253)
    at V1 (https://pillser.com/assets/entry.client-tQKe0HOj.js:42:71620)
    at zd (https://pillser.com/assets/entry.client-tQKe0HOj.js:42:113985)
    at Jm (https://pillser.com/assets/entry.client-tQKe0HOj.js:42:113122)
    at Ze (https://pillser.com/assets/entry.client-tQKe0HOj.js:42:112950)
    at od (https://pillser.com/assets/entry.client-tQKe0HOj.js:42:110250)
    at hd (https://pillser.com/assets/entry.client-tQKe0HOj.js:42:109636)
    at MessagePort.H (https://pillser.com/assets/entry.client-tQKe0HOj.js:27:1537)

Refreshing the same page made the error go away, which makes me think it is some odd transient state issue.
I also noticed that errors increase in frequency around the time that I deploy a new version of the application.
Worth noting that I also don't directly use useMemoCache anywhere in my codebase. The only place I see this function referenced is inside react-compiler-runtime.development.js.
From what I can tell, the code actually originates from this like of code:
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/7954db9398b9afa962167577a6c6940be3856c39/compiler/packages/react-compiler-runtime/src/index.ts#L88

Appears to be related to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/29755

Any chance you aren't following any of these in your code (especially 2): https://react.dev/learn/react-compiler#what-does-the-compiler-assume ?

Seems unlikely as I have tsconfig.json strict set to true, and ESLint rule is not reporting any rules from react-compiler` ruleset.
